# How to call API using dictionary within URL using Python?

Tags: python

If I put the parameters within the URL like:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?symbols=GBP&base=USD"

payload = {
}

headers= {
  "apikey": "*****"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

status_code = response.status_code
result = response.text

print (result)
```

It works. But trying...

```
import requests

url = "https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest?symbols={symbols}&base={base}"

payload = [{
    "base": "USD",
    "symbols": "GBP"

}]

headers= {
  "apikey": "*****"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

status_code = response.status_code
result = response.text

print (result)
```

Does not work. How do I use the dictionary correctly? Obviously being able to use a parameter is way more useful than manually changing the url.

Comment: Strange enough the docs cover this [URL parameters](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

Comment: Suppose, you followed the docs and example hinted by @Adrian .. What exactly "Does not work." ?

Comment: The code was provided by apilayer and worked in the demo, within the browser, but not within my IDE and couldn't work out why. Barmar's answer helped

Answer (score 1):

Use the `params` option to `requests.get()`. It will automatically add the query parameters, you don't have to write placeholders yourself.

`payload` should be a single dictionary, not a list.

```
import requests

url = "https://api.apilayer.com/fixer/latest"

payload = {
    "base": "USD",
    "symbols": "GBP"
}

headers= {
  "apikey": "*****"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params = payload)

status_code = response.status_code
result = response.text

print (result)
```

Comment: Removing the "GET" and everything past latest worked, thank you very much